# Is it possible to make multiple fields default to the same date, but also be individually editable?

Tags: date, ms-access

I am VERY new to Access - I was sort of thrust into designing a database for a research project I'm involved in. So, please bear with me because I know next to nothing :) The problem I am having is thus:

My database is for a medical research project, and is very time and date dependent, by which I mean I need to capture the date and time for each piece of data so that we end up with a sort of timeline of events for each subject.

As is, I have something like the following for each piece of data: (Each in it's own field)

ArrivalDate

ArrivalTime

HeartRateDate

HeartRateTime

HeartRateData

TemperatureDate

TemperatureTime

TemperatureData

BloodPressureDate

BloodPressureTime

BloodPressureData

There are around 200 similar pieces of data that I need to collect for each patient. To avoid having to re-enter the same data over and over, and also to reduce the potential for error, I would like to have all of the date fields in a given patient record default to the first one that is entered, in this case "Arrival Date". However, I also need each date field to be editable without affecting the others.  The reason for this is that in the event that a patient's visit occurs over the span of a few days we can accurately record that.

I have tried messing around with the default value setting, as well as setting the control source to reference the "Arrival Date" field, but then of course any changes to one field affect them all.  I am not even sure that what I am trying to do is possible but I will appreciate any help and/or suggestions!

Thank you in advance

Comment: Why have separate date and time fields, instead of single fields containing a datetime?

Comment: This seems like something you should implement in the application used to enter the data, not the database schema.

Comment: If you want to have the ArrivalDate be the default, that will require code - VBA or macro. Over 200 pieces of data means what - 200 different stats? A table has a limit of 255 fields. Your data structure is not truly normalized.

Comment: I've got multiple tables.  Prior to my arrival at this job all data entry was done in Excel.  We do not have access to a true data collection system, and so they have tasked me with coming up with one in Access.  As it stands, my tables and forms work just fine for their purposes, but this one issue with the date is bothering me.

Answer (score 1):

Having all this data in separate columns of a big table isn't going to work. You don't measure things like temperature or blood pressure only once per patient, do you?

This is a classic one-to-many relation.

You should have a separate `Measurements` table, looking e.g. like this:

```
+--------+-----------+---------------+------------------+-----------+
| MeasID | PatientID |   MeasType    |   MeasDateTime   | MeasValue |
+--------+-----------+---------------+------------------+-----------+
|      1 |         1 | Temperature   | 2017-05-17 14:30 | 38.2      |
|      2 |         1 | BloodPressure | 2017-05-17 14:30 | 130/90    |
|      3 |         1 | Temperature   | 2017-05-17 18:00 | 38.5      |
|      4 |         2 | Temperature   | etc.             |           |
+--------+-----------+---------------+------------------+-----------+
```

As Barmar wrote, there is no reason to have separate columns for date and time.

In the form where measurements are entered, you can use the `BeforeInsert` event to set `MeasDateTime` to the current time, with the `Now()` function.

So the user never has to enter it manually, but they can edit it if the measurement was at a different time than entering the data.

Comment: I should have mentioned that all of our data is retrospective, collected from charts from several years ago, so having the date default to the current date will not work. That is the reason I separated out the date and time into separate columns.